# How can I create a list of a generic type that will be passed as a parameter (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, generics

say I have two POCOs I'm using in EF code first

```
Public class C1
    property F1 as integer
End Class

Public class C2
    property F2 as String
End Class
```

I want to have a function that will create a list either of C1 or C2, to be used in some generic operation, such that

```
Sub MySub(type_of_class)
    private lst as new List(of type_of_class)
    ...
End Sub
```

Will either create a list of C1 or of C2.

I know generics are probably the answer by my knowlege is kind of generic :-)

thanks!

Comment: Generic Type parameters have to be supplied at compile time, not run time, so what you're trying above will not work. In addition, what could MySub usefully do once it had constructed such a list? Perhaps you can describe the *problem* you're actually trying to solve that led you to thinking that the above would be part of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics is your answer, but there is a lot more to it.
Your sub should be:

```
Public Sub MySub(Of T)()

    Dim MyT As T

    'do stuff with T

End Sub
```

and called as this

```
MySub(Of C1)()
```

For more (starting) info: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx)

Success, Marcel